# qemu-img: Could not open '/dev/stdin': Could not refresh total sector count: Operation not permitted

Tags: qemu, qcow2

I want to transfer block device contents over the network directly into a `qcow2` image. I started with a small simulation:

```
[root@okvmh1 default]# dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=100 | qemu-img convert -p -f raw -O qcow2 /dev/stdin aaa.qcow2
qemu-img: Could not open '/dev/stdin': Could not refresh total sector count: Operation not permitted
qemu-img: Could not open '/dev/stdin'
```

It seems that `qemu-img` does not know the desired image size. In `VirtualBox` I would do:

```
<net-command> | VBoxManage convertfromraw stdin aaa.vdi $size --format VDI
```

But `qemu-img convert` does not accept the size parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard input is not *seekable*, which is what qemu-img convert is trying to do here.

To work around the problem, use an input image which is a file on the filesystem or a block device, both of which are seekable.

Answer (score 2):

## Emulate a Device over a QCOW2 image

Although this is an old question I think it should be worth to show an interesting alternative.
I had the same problem, but the provided answer from [Michael Hampton](https://serverfault.com/a/765690/345452) would not fit for me as the amount of data I had to transfer was too big and the time I had to do the operation would not be enough.
So below is what I made:

### Create an empty QCOW2 image

In destination, create an empty QCOW2 image, for example:

```
$ qemu-img create -f qcow2 myimage.qcow2 500g
```

### Connect the QCOW2 image using NBD to a device

There is a tool that allows you to emulate a device on top of a QCOW2 image. This is mostly used to get access to QCOW2 contents, but the device is read-writable so you can treat it as a standard block device:

```
$ modprobe nbd
$ qemu-nbd --connect /dev/nbd0 myimage.qcow2
```

Now you have a `/dev/nbd0` device that is a block device just like any block device but any operation done over it will be performed on the QCOW2 image

### Perform the transfer over the emulated device

You can use any network command, for example `ssh` and `dd` to make the magic work:

```
$ dd if=myoriginalimg bs=100M | pv -tebrap --size 500g | ssh myhost dd of=/dev/nbd0 bs=100M
```

I added a plus using `pv` so you can monitor the progress. I further advice you to run this command inside a `screen` or `tmux` session if it may take very long so you do not loose your job!

### Close the emulator

After the transfer is complete, you have a ready and converted QCOW2 image on `myimage.qcow2`, but make sure you disconnect the emulator so kernel don't get angry on you!

```
$ qemu-nbd --disconnect /dev/nbd0
```

You are done! Now you have a ready converted image transmitted from a raw format from a network origin directly to a QCOW2 file without intermediates

Answer (score 0):

Streaming disk images using `dd` or similar is not a good idea because it doesn't preserve sparseness.  Nevertheless if you don't care about that [there is an nbdkit plugin which can do exactly what you want](https://github.com/libguestfs/nbdkit/commit/2aa7b35fa9251bf564cf6b1cd795dd1a7c3b67b0).  You will still need to know the virtual size in advance because qcow2 needs to know that in order to create the qcow2 container.